# Angular dynamically file writing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, writefile

I have an application which is rendering a VR scene with an Angular component and some other files. Now some of files are hardcoded and i can start always only one scene. So i gave an opportunity for a client to load this files to a backend and then user will be given a choise to choose a scene to start. When he choose a scene and clicked start, i am reading this files from a backend. Now i have all files content as a plaintext and i only needed to write files for scene execution with this data. I tried "fs" library to write files or FileWriter, but using both of them are creating errors. Using "fs" provides a lot of installations and erros. FileWriter i don't have at all as available class.

```
startTask(i: number) {
    let taskFiles: TaskFiles;
    this.task_files_subscription = this._client.getTaskFiles(this.tasks[i].id).subscribe(data => {
      taskFiles = data as TaskFiles;
      TaskFiles.decode(taskFiles);

      const htmlFilePath = '<path>/scene.component.html';
      const tsFilePath = '<path>/scene.component.ts';
      // ... other files

      console.log("success");
    })
  }
```

Here is TaskFiles class:

```
export class TaskFiles {
  htmlFile: string = "";
  tsFile: string = "";
  specTsFile: string = "";
  pnmlFile: string = "";
  languageFile: string = "";

  public constructor(init?: Partial<TaskFiles>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }

  // decode method to decode base64 to a plaintext
}
```

Is there a good way to solve my problem with writing files? If yes, how to write files with some data? Or it can be a better way to do it?

Comment: No such thing writing files in the client side, that's not how the web browser works. Your server side should handle that and write to a static folder path.

Comment: @penleychan Did I understand correctly that on the backend side I can write these files to a folder located in the frontend part. Since I'm using modules this will be possible, but isn't it a problem if the projects are in different root paths. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Server side can do a lot provided you give sufficient permissions to write to that path.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has a major flaw to begin with :

Typescript files are transpiled to javascript, Angular won't be to do anything with typescript files a runtime.

So don't expect to be able to send components from a server.

You can only have dynamic templates, downloaded from the server. But that requires to embed the JIT compiler in the build which is not really recommanded for performance reasons.